# CSR color coding row of list not showing correctly when list is filtered

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, client-side-rendering, ctx

Before i show my code, let me give some background.
I am using JSLink in the webpart of the list. I have MDS disabled for the site.
my javascript file is located in my root sitecollection in Style library.

this list works correctly at first but when filtered it looses the color until the list is refreshed.  I have tried the skipanimation line as well, and it did nothing.

```
(function () {

  var overrideCtx = {};
  overrideCtx.Templates = {};

  overrideCtx.OnPostRender = [
    HighlightRowOverride
  ];

  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

}) ();

function HighlightRowOverride (inCtx) {

  // for each item (row)
  for (var i = 0; i < inCtx.ListData.Row.length; ++i) {
    var listItem = inCtx.ListData.Row [i];

    var iid = GenerateIIDForListItem(inCtx, listItem);
    var row = document.getElementById(iid);

    if (listItem.Status == "Stale") {
      if (row != null) {
        row.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)"; //red
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: this is running on sharepoint 2016

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
  (function(){
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want     to change it's output render
    var statusFiledContext= {};
    statusFiledContext.Templates = {};
    statusFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
      //Apply the new redenring for nom du projet field on the list view
      "status" : {"View" : statusFiledTemplate}
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFiledContext);
  })();
  
  //this function provides our purpose
  function statusFiledTemplate(ctx){
    var status= ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
  switch (status) { 
              case "Stale": 
                  return "<span style='color :#f00'>" + status + "</span>"; 
                  break; 
              case "Pending": 
                  return "<span style='color :#ff6a00'>" + status + "</span>"; 
                  break; 
              case "Rejected": 
                  return "<span style='color :#cab023'>" + status + "</span>"; 
          } 
  }
</script>
```

Test result:

[image]

**Updated code:**

```
<script>
(function () {
    var overrideCurrentContext = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.OnPostRender = renderItem;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);
})();


function renderItem() {
    
    if (ctx.ListTitle == "test4") {
        var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var status = rows[i]["status"];            

            var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
            var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
            if (row != null && status=="Pending" ) {
                row.style.backgroundColor = '#ffcccc';
            }
            
        }

        ctx.skipNextAnimation = true;
    }
   
}

</script>
```

Comment: I am looking to do entire row, not the text or background color of the column cell. but thanks for that.

Comment: Check the updated.

Comment: does not work for me either as a JSlink in the webpart or as a code snippet in a script editor web part.

Comment: in the code you provided, I changed 'test4' to the title of my list 'FullRowColor'. I changed

Comment: if (ctx.ListTitle == "test4") to "FullRowColor",  var status = rows[i]["status"]; to Status as as my column is capitalized. if (row != null && status=="Pending" ) to Stale as Stale is the value that i want the row color changed on.

Comment: i even tried deleting the status column and re adding it.  did i do something wrong.?

Comment: That's not the point.I try your code,it works well too.You could try to debug the code,to check the listItem.Status value.